# Restrict to 2 digits after decimal point in Price

Tags: price

we are using following code to display price in frontend.

```
 <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span>
    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />
```

in frontend price is displaying as follows.
suppose if price is 100, than its displaying as 100.0000 .

after decimal points, 4 zeros [numbers] are displaying. I want to restrict to only 2 numbers after decimal point.

Comment: try this  number_format($products->getPrice(), 2, '.', '')

Comment: try using number_format($products->getPrice(), 2);

Comment: i tried this, but it did't worked : <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo number_format($products->getPrice(), 2, '.', '') ?>" style = "display:none"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the product price with currency

```
Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false);
```

Refer this [Link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-format-price/)

### Edit :

Update your code like this

```
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?></span> 
<input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>" style = "display:none"/>
```

Get Price without currency

```
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($products->getPrice(), array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL)); ?></span> 
<input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($products->getPrice(), array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL)); ?>" style = "display:none"/>
```

Comment: can you please give complete code, because  i am adding this code at the top : <?php Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>   but its not working

Comment: `<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>` this will return value right?

Comment: yes, you are right......

Comment: `Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false);` does this return any error?

Comment: no errors, but still 4 decimal digits are displaying.....

Comment: is i have to do any modification for the above code?

Comment: i am using code like this : <?php Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>             
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>

Comment: you have put echo see the out put.
`<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>`

Comment: i tried this : <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>  
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo
 $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>    but same result......

Comment: you need to replace the that code in `value="<?php //code comes here?>"`

Comment: sorry, please check now : is this right code :      <?php Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>            
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>   but not working......

Comment: try this <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?></span> <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($products->getPrice(), true, false); ?>" style = "display:none"/>

Comment: please post your comment as answer....

Comment: check the answer

Comment: i dont need currrency, i need only 2 digits.... please give me updated code

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the currency helper like below:

```
<?php $price = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($products->getPrice(), array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL));?>
 <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $price; ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $price; ?>" />
```

Comment: i am getting this error : Fatal error: Call to a member function getPrice() on a non-object in

Comment: Sorry, now is ok.

Comment: its still displaying 4 zeros.....

Comment: Did you clean the cache?

Comment: ya, but still 4 digits.....

Comment: cache was disabled......